# Why is my seven segment display only showing 0's?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, clock, keypad, seven-segment-display

I am trying to write code for my Nexys 4 DDR to display 4 digits which are chosen from a keypad.
They keypad is fed into port JA and then decoded and displayed on the seven segment displays.  The numbers are supposed to shift left after a new key is pressed.
As of now, my code is generating a bitstream but the displays only show 0's and the reset button seems to be functioning.  I'm not sure if this is a clock issue or an inconsistency somewhere in my code?

I've attached my design sources and my constraint file.
Thanks.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;


entity PmodKYPD_Nexsy4 is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in STD_LOGIC;
           JA : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);    -- PmodKYPD connected to Pmod JA
           an : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);      -- Controls which position of the 8 seven segment displays to display
           seg: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0));     -- digit to display on seven segment display
end PmodKYPD_Nexsy4;

architecture Behavioral of PmodKYPD_Nexsy4 is


component DisplayController is
    Port ( DispVal : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           Selector : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           anode : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           segOut : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0));
end component;

signal Decode: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
signal RegLast : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
signal refresh : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (19 downto 0);
signal LEDAct : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);


signal Row : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
signal Col : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
signal sclk :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(19 downto 0);
signal DecodeOut : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);

signal Reg : unsigned(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin

Row <= JA(7 downto 4);
Col <= JA(3 downto 0);


process(clk,reset)
begin 
    if(reset='1') then
        refresh <= (others => '0');
    elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
        refresh <= refresh + 1;
    end if;
end process;

LEDAct <= refresh(19 downto 18);

process(clk)
    begin
        if clk'event and clk = '1' then
            -- 1ms
            if sclk = "00011000011010100000" then 
                --C1
                Col<= "0111";
                sclk <= sclk+1;
            -- check row pins
            elsif sclk = "00011000011010101000" then    
                --R1
                if Row = "0111" then
                    DecodeOut <= "0001";    --1
                --R2
                elsif Row = "1011" then
                    DecodeOut <= "0100"; --4
                --R3
                elsif Row = "1101" then
                    DecodeOut <= "0111"; --7
                --R4
                elsif Row = "1110" then
                    DecodeOut <= "1111"; --F (mod from "0000"; --0)
                end if;
                sclk <= sclk+1;
            -- 2ms
            elsif sclk = "00110000110101000000" then    
                --C2
                Col<= "1011";
                sclk <= sclk+1;
            -- check row pins
            elsif sclk = "00110000110101001000" then    
                --R1
                if Row = "0111" then        
                    DecodeOut <= "0010"; --2
                --R2
                elsif Row = "1011" then
                    DecodeOut <= "0101"; --5
                --R3
                elsif Row = "1101" then
                    DecodeOut <= "1000"; --8
                --R4
                elsif Row = "1110" then
                    DecodeOut <= "0000"; --0 (mod from "1111"; --F)
                end if;
                sclk <= sclk+1; 
            --3ms
            elsif sclk = "01001001001111100000" then 
                --C3
                Col<= "1101";
                sclk <= sclk+1;
            -- check row pins
            elsif sclk = "01001001001111101000" then 
                --R1
                if Row = "0111" then
                    DecodeOut <= "0011"; --3    
                --R2
                elsif Row = "1011" then
                    DecodeOut <= "0110"; --6
                --R3
                elsif Row = "1101" then
                    DecodeOut <= "1001"; --9
                --R4
                elsif Row = "1110" then
                    DecodeOut <= "1110"; --E
                end if;
                sclk <= sclk+1;
            --4ms
            elsif sclk = "01100001101010000000" then            
                --C4
                Col<= "1110";
                sclk <= sclk+1;
            -- check row pins
            elsif sclk = "01100001101010001000" then 
                --R1
                if Row = "0111" then
                    DecodeOut <= "1010"; --A
                --R2
                elsif Row = "1011" then
                    DecodeOut <= "1011"; --B
                --R3
                elsif Row = "1101" then
                    DecodeOut <= "1100"; --C
                --R4
                elsif Row = "1110" then
                    DecodeOut <= "1101"; --D
                end if;
                sclk <= "00000000000000000000"; 
            else
                sclk <= sclk+1; 
            end if;
        end if;
end process;

SHIFT_REG : process(clk)
variable tmp : unsigned(15 downto 0);
    begin
        if clk'event and clk = '1' then
            tmp := Reg;
            tmp := tmp sll 4;
            tmp(3 downto 0) := unsigned(DecodeOut);
            Reg <= tmp;
        end if;
end process;

    C0: DisplayController port map (DispVal=>STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(Reg), Selector=>LEDAct, anode=>an, segOut=>seg );

end Behavioral;
```

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity DisplayController is
    Port ( DispVal : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           Selector : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           anode : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           segOut : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0));
end DisplayController;

architecture Behavioral of DisplayController is

begin


process(Selector)
begin
    case Selector is
    when "00" =>
        anode <= "11110111"; 
        -- activate LED1 and Deactivate LED2, LED3, LED4
        -- the first hex digit of the 16-bit number
        case DispVal(15 downto 12) is       -- active low to display segment
                      when "0000" => SegOut <= "1000000"; --0
                      when "0001" => SegOut <= "1111001"; --1
                      when "0010" => SegOut <= "0100100"; --2
                      when "0011" => SegOut <= "0110000"; --3
                      when "0100" => SegOut <= "0011001"; --4
                      when "0101" => SegOut <= "0010010"; --5
                      when "0110" => SegOut <= "0000010"; --6
                      when "0111" => SegOut <= "1111000"; --7
                      when "1000" => SegOut <= "0000000"; --8
                      when "1001" => SegOut <= "0010000"; --9
                      when "1010" => SegOut <= "0001000"; --A
                      when "1011" => SegOut <= "0000011"; --B
                      when "1100" => SegOut <= "1000110"; --C
                      when "1101" => SegOut <= "0100001"; --D
                      when "1110" => SegOut <= "0000110"; --E
                      when "1111" => SegOut <= "0001110"; --F
                      when others => Segout <= "0111111";
        end case;

    when "01" =>
        anode <= "11111011"; 
        -- activate LED2 and Deactivate LED1, LED3, LED4
        -- the second hex digit of the 16-bit number
        case DispVal(11 downto 8) is       -- active low to display segment
                      when "0000" => SegOut <= "1000000"; --0
                      when "0001" => SegOut <= "1111001"; --1
                      when "0010" => SegOut <= "0100100"; --2
                      when "0011" => SegOut <= "0110000"; --3
                      when "0100" => SegOut <= "0011001"; --4
                      when "0101" => SegOut <= "0010010"; --5
                      when "0110" => SegOut <= "0000010"; --6
                      when "0111" => SegOut <= "1111000"; --7
                      when "1000" => SegOut <= "0000000"; --8
                      when "1001" => SegOut <= "0010000"; --9
                      when "1010" => SegOut <= "0001000"; --A
                      when "1011" => SegOut <= "0000011"; --B
                      when "1100" => SegOut <= "1000110"; --C
                      when "1101" => SegOut <= "0100001"; --D
                      when "1110" => SegOut <= "0000110"; --E
                      when "1111" => SegOut <= "0001110"; --F
                      when others => Segout <= "0111111";
        end case;

    when "10" =>
        anode <= "11111101"; 
        -- activate LED3 and Deactivate LED2, LED1, LED4
        -- the third hex digit of the 16-bit number
        case DispVal(7 downto 4) is       -- active low to display segment
                      when "0000" => SegOut <= "1000000"; --0
                      when "0001" => SegOut <= "1111001"; --1
                      when "0010" => SegOut <= "0100100"; --2
                      when "0011" => SegOut <= "0110000"; --3
                      when "0100" => SegOut <= "0011001"; --4
                      when "0101" => SegOut <= "0010010"; --5
                      when "0110" => SegOut <= "0000010"; --6
                      when "0111" => SegOut <= "1111000"; --7
                      when "1000" => SegOut <= "0000000"; --8
                      when "1001" => SegOut <= "0010000"; --9
                      when "1010" => SegOut <= "0001000"; --A
                      when "1011" => SegOut <= "0000011"; --B
                      when "1100" => SegOut <= "1000110"; --C
                      when "1101" => SegOut <= "0100001"; --D
                      when "1110" => SegOut <= "0000110"; --E
                      when "1111" => SegOut <= "0001110"; --F
                      when others => Segout <= "0111111";
        end case;

    when "11" =>
        anode <= "11111110"; 
        -- activate LED4 and Deactivate LED2, LED3, LED1
        -- the fourth hex digit of the 16-bit number    
        case DispVal(3 downto 0) is       -- active low to display segment
                      when "0000" => SegOut <= "1000000"; --0
                      when "0001" => SegOut <= "1111001"; --1
                      when "0010" => SegOut <= "0100100"; --2
                      when "0011" => SegOut <= "0110000"; --3
                      when "0100" => SegOut <= "0011001"; --4
                      when "0101" => SegOut <= "0010010"; --5
                      when "0110" => SegOut <= "0000010"; --6
                      when "0111" => SegOut <= "1111000"; --7
                      when "1000" => SegOut <= "0000000"; --8
                      when "1001" => SegOut <= "0010000"; --9
                      when "1010" => SegOut <= "0001000"; --A
                      when "1011" => SegOut <= "0000011"; --B
                      when "1100" => SegOut <= "1000110"; --C
                      when "1101" => SegOut <= "0100001"; --D
                      when "1110" => SegOut <= "0000110"; --E
                      when "1111" => SegOut <= "0001110"; --F
                      when others => Segout <= "0111111";
        end case;

end case;
end process;


end Behavioral;
```

```
## Clock signal
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E3    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { clk }]; #IO_L12P_T1_MRCC_35 Sch=clk100mhz
create_clock -add -name sys_clk_pin -period 10.00 -waveform {0 5} [get_ports {clk}];

##7 segment display
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T10   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { seg[0] }]; #IO_L24N_T3_A00_D16_14 Sch=ca
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R10   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { seg[1] }]; #IO_25_14 Sch=cb
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN K16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { seg[2] }]; #IO_25_15 Sch=cc
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN K13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { seg[3] }]; #IO_L17P_T2_A26_15 Sch=cd
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN P15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { seg[4] }]; #IO_L13P_T2_MRCC_14 Sch=ce
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T11   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { seg[5] }]; #IO_L19P_T3_A10_D26_14 Sch=cf
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN L18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { seg[6] }]; #IO_L4P_T0_D04_14 Sch=cg

set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { an[0] }]; #IO_L23P_T3_FOE_B_15 Sch=an[0]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { an[1] }]; #IO_L23N_T3_FWE_B_15 Sch=an[1]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T9    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { an[2] }]; #IO_L24P_T3_A01_D17_14 Sch=an[2]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { an[3] }]; #IO_L19P_T3_A22_15 Sch=an[3]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN P14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { an[4] }]; #IO_L8N_T1_D12_14 Sch=an[4]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { an[5] }]; #IO_L14P_T2_SRCC_14 Sch=an[5]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN K2    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { an[6] }]; #IO_L23P_T3_35 Sch=an[6]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN U13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { an[7] }]; #IO_L23N_T3_A02_D18_14 Sch=an[7]

##Buttons
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN N17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { reset }]; #IO_L9P_T1_DQS_14 Sch=btnc

##Pmod Header JA
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN C17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[0] }]; #IO_L20N_T3_A19_15 Sch=ja[1]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[1] }]; #IO_L21N_T3_DQS_A18_15 Sch=ja[2]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[2] }]; #IO_L21P_T3_DQS_15 Sch=ja[3]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN G17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[3] }]; #IO_L18N_T2_A23_15 Sch=ja[4]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[4] }]; #IO_L16N_T2_A27_15 Sch=ja[7]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[5] }]; #IO_L16P_T2_A28_15 Sch=ja[8]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN F18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[6] }]; #IO_L22N_T3_A16_15 Sch=ja[9]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN G18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[7] }]; #IO_L22P_T3_A17_15 Sch=ja[10]
```

Comment: You don't show a test-bench. Did you write one? If not: always, always, **always** make a test-bench when you HDL code is more then a few lines of code.

Comment: I did not, I'm very new to VHDL.  Would it be simple to create a testbench?

Comment: One of the case statements needs an others statement and the inout mode port for ja  gives you problems. Scan the keypad by pulling down (driving low) each COL pin one at a time while monitoring ROW signals (and debouncing). `You need ja(3 downto 0) <= col; ` not the other way around.  You should be getting a synthesis report of multiple drivers for `col` the way it is, the unlabeled process from decoder.vhd in the demo code and the concurrent assignment (` col <= ja(3 downto 0);`).

Comment: Simulation could be made quicker by passing a generic for clocks per second and producing constants from that in place of the bit string literals you use for sclk.  A 100 MHz clock means a lot of simulator events.

Comment: *" Would it be simple to create a testbench?"* The usual answer is 'it depends' To give you an impressions: I spend 5-10% of my time designing the circuit, the rest goes up in the test bench. But I suspect my designs are a bit more complex then yours. (But even for a simple design my ratio is ~50/50.) It is very easy to have a temporal error in HDL designs. You can't step through the code in hardware. Thus you write a test-bench or spend hours connecting , re-connecting and running with an ILA (In-circuit Logic Analyser).

Comment: While it may sound excessive spending 10% of time on the design and 90% on the testbench, usually time spend in simulation is worth at least double trying to debug the same bugs on hardware (if not much longer). So while it can take a while to learn (and sometimes you'll get pressure from management to "just get it on hardware"), it will always pay off in the end

Comment: @Tricky This is in ASIC design. For an FPGA you can gamble but not in ASICs. Also all our test-benches have to be self-verifying with code coverage above 98%.

Comment: @Oldfart The same holds true for FPGA. Time spent in a testbench is worth double debugging on hardware. Unfortunately managers dont always see that and are annoyingly happy to release a buggy product, only for customers to find the bugs and complain. Ive worked in FPGA teams where we had a verification team working in UVM. The bug return after release to software was far less than previous, and most bugs came about because of weak or poorly interpreted specs.